# What explains a green laser reflecting off an orange ping pong ball producing bright yellow?

Tags: visible-light, laser

I shined a green laser pointer at an orange ping pong ball today and saw a distinctly bright yellow color.

At first I thought about it and reasoned that green=(yellow + blue) hits the ball which reflects orange=(yellow + red) thus yellow is reflected.

Then I thought, wouldn't this mean that a prism would break a green laser into yellow and blue?  A quick search confirmed this is obviously not the case since laser light is a single wavelength, not an additive combination of primaries...

What then is a good explanation for this?
[image]

Comment: This is definitely not going to be as easy as green=yellow+blue, because atoms don't share our color perception when they figure out their energy levels.  This https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72560/  is a very similar question you probably want to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laser light from a green laser pointer is essentially monochromatic. I demonstrated that in [this earlier answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/191223/26969) which shows how to measure the wavelength - in the process of that experiment you see the spectrum consists of a single peak.

I hypothesize that your orange pingpong ball is fluorescent (this is often done to make the ball more visible: see [this article](http://thepingpongguy.weebly.com/blog/orange-and-white-ping-pong-ball-which-one) for more details. As that article mentions, white balls are used in tournaments, where the table, floor and clothing are dark-colored, lighting is sufficient, and white will provide better contrast).

As the green light has a shorter wavelength (higher energy) than the emission wavelength of the phosphor, you excite the phosphor in the ball - and it then emits the longer wavelength of light.

You see a similar thing if you use a 405 nm (almost invisible, near UV) laser pointer and shine it at a piece of white paper. The paper contains compounds that fluoresce, and the resulting beam suddenly goes from "barely visible purple" to "bright blue".

Comment: High quality business cards make great UV laser viewing cards (until you burn a hole in them).

Comment: @JonCuster I didn't know that. Watch your eyes - a UV laser nearly cost me my eye sight.

Comment: You beat me to it.  It will be fluorescence, possibly [RFP](https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/life-science/cell-analysis/fluorophores/red-fluorescent-protein.html) which is excited by 532nm lasers.  The reason for this will be to make the ball optically brighter under light which has little or no UV but a decent amount of green: indoors, in other words.

Comment: @tfb you are absolutely right - it is intended to make the ball more visible. I will add that to my answer. In my native language, we would call such a color "lichtgevend" (giving off light) because the object would often look unnaturally bright. Especially if it could convert some invisible (UV) light from the environment.

Comment: @Floris - hence the viewing card (with appropriate laser goggles)! And they don't have to be 'charged' like the IR viewer cards.

Comment: @JonCuster "with appropriate laser goggles" is key...

Comment: Absolutely! As the (grad student) laser safety officer with a 4J/pulse YAG laser with double/triple/quadrupled output wavelengths we were very respectful and careful...

Comment: I am talking about a 50 mW 405 nm laser pointer you can buy for $20 online... "it doesn't look so bright" while you look at the dot it makes on the wall, and then you have a spot in your vision. Lesson.Learnt.